# How check for a specific sprite class in a list

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

This is my current inventory system and I am working on having it register when an item has been picked up, but I am having trouble getting the program to register when the sprite class has been added to the list.

```
import pygame
import Constants
import item_sys
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(Constants.screen_size)
inv = pygame.image.load("inv.png").convert_alpha()

gunx = -200
guny = -200

#sprite groups
item_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Invent_Sys():

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = []
        self.inventory_state = False
        self.sqaure = 36
    def uninventory(self):
        self.inventory_state = False

    def inventory_u(self):

        ITEMS,time_ms_mine = pygame.USEREVENT +1, 60
        pygame.time.set_timer(ITEMS, time_ms_mine)

        while self.inventory_state:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x = pos[0]
            y = pos[1]
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
            print(self.inventory)
            screen.blit(inv,(0,0))
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit

                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    print(pos)

                elif event.type == ITEMS:
                    for i, j in enumerate(self.inventory):
                        if j == item_sys.Item1:
                            print('test') 
                            gunx = 14
                            guny = 395
                            gun = item_sys.Item1(gunx,guny)
                            gun.rect.x = gunx
                            gun.rect.y = guny
                            item_list.add(gun)
```

Comment: Does this inventory system code fail here: `if j == item_sys.Item1:` hence your question about checking for/registering when a specific Sprite class (Item) is added to the list?

Comment: If you notice the print("test") nothing comes up at all and the sprite doesnt show up

Comment: And just to make sure, your actual code is indented correctly compared to what you've put in your post? Notice the `print('test')` and subsequent statements are not indented correctly.

Comment: I fixed it so it properly shows what is being indented correctly

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest using either the [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function or the [class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) attribute to determine what type of class the object is and let me know the results of that. (If the above helps, I'll turn it into an answer). Another way you could approach this is to add a function `GetItemType()` to your `Item1` class that returns the item type e.g. weapon, armour, potion, etc. This is something that would no doubt come in handy as you continue to build your game.

Comment: I dont fully understand how the type function or the class attributes work as I am not fully fluent in python as I am just learning it as I go and what I got from my Grade 11 programing class

Comment: Okay, I'm going to assume `Item1` isn't a sub class (if it is, then you'll have to look into [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)). So, try `if type(j) is Item1:`. Broadly speaking, `type` and `__class__` allow you to check what something is a type of which is the answer to your question. That little bit of code I wrote, you could read it like this: "if  `j`s class/type is `Item1` class, then do the following ..."

Comment: Thank you so much Jon that actually worked, I have one more question for you, how would I check that the mouse was clicked on a sprite, and then have it tether to the mouse until I put it into a pixel area?

Comment: In other words, how can you click, drag and drop an item into a slot for equipping/unequipping?

Comment: Yes exactly move an item from one slot to another

Comment: As that's a separate question, either ask a separate question on Stack Overflow, or do some research on pygame drag and drop as there are many examples out there. Once you hit a sticking point, ask a question and I'll assist.

Try break the problem down into manageable chunks, so, for example:
1. How can I tell if the mouse is hovering over an item in the inventory?
2. How do I _pick up_ the item with the mouse cursor?
3. How do I move the item with the mouse cursor?
4. How can I tell if the item is _dropped_ on a slot?
5. How can I tell if the slot it is dropped on is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if j == item_sys.Item1` check will fail because it is not checking the *type* of `j` equals *class type*. Rather, it is checking if the *value/object* `j` equals *class type*.

So, what you need to do is get `j`s *type*. To do that, assuming `Item1` class is not a subclass (if it is, you will need to make use of [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)), you can use `if type(j) is Item1`. You can read this as: 'if `j` is a type of `Item1`'.

To avoid runtime type checking (which is what you are doing here), I'd recommend implementing a method in your `Item1` class that returns the item type e.g. weapon, armour, consumable, et cetera as that will come in handy as you develop your game.

You could go one step further and implement a method in your `Item1` class that gets the item's sub type e.g. weapon -> gun, sword, stave, et cetera.